# Legendary Encounters - Alien: Freeing captives in the "Who's laying the eggs?" objective (spoilers)

Tags: legendary-alien

When can you start freeing captives in the *"Who's laying the eggs?"* Objective ?

- As soon as this objective becomes the current one
- When this objective is the current one, but only after an Event card has been drawn
- As soon as there are captives (no need to wait for this to be the current objective)
- Other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can begin to free the captives as soon as *Who's Laying the Eggs?* becomes the current objective.

From the [rulebook](https://www.upperdeck.com/OP/RuleBooks/Legendary_Encounters_Rules-Alien.pdf) (page 11):

> The players can only be on one “current objective” at a time. Whenever an Objective is completed, immediately put it on the bottom of the three Objective cards. Players can then work toward completing the next Objective.

This means that you cannot be working on future objectives, so could not use the text relating to buying captives before this objective becomes current.

As soon as the objective is the current one, you can use the text on it to buy the captives. While there is no explicit rules explaining this, the text for resolving events and for purchasing captives are separated, which indicates they are different abilities, so the second ability would not require the event trigger of the first.

Comment: thanks for the answer!
Regarding the tag change you made, I thought that Legendary and Legendary Encounters were two different animals ( that's why i created a new tag in the first place)
Sorry if that's not the case...

Comment: No worries, regarding the tag, others may think differently, I was just following suit with the existing [legendary-marvel] and [legendary-firefly] tag format.